# SASS solution to make inherited css styles disjoint

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I'm using [Bulma] CSS framework[1](https://bulma.io). This CSS framework provides default styles for tabs and dropdowns. For the tabs, it has (also) the following CSS

```
.tabs.is-boxed a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

while for dropdowns it has

```
a.dropdown-item {
  padding-right: 3rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #0a0a0a;
}

a.dropdown-item.is-active {
  background-color: #3273dc;
  color: #fff;
}
```

It means that if you have an html that more or less looks like the    following

```
<div class="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li>

     <!-- DROPDOWN GOES HERE -->   
     <div class="dropdown is-active">
       <div class="dropdown-trigger">
         <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
           <span>Dropdown button</span>
           <span class="icon is-small">
             <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </span>
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <div class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
             Dropdown item
           </a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <!-- DROPDOWN ENDS -->

   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

then the style applied to all the anchors included in the `tabs` class is also applied to the anchors in the dropdown. This will results in an horrible rendering.

Of course I could write my own CSS, but I think that it would be an horrible solution against common sense and design principles.

I wonder if I can fix somehow this situation by using SASS or just CSS in order to make the styles applied to the anchors that have the `.dropdown-item` disjoint by the one defined by `tabs.a`.

Comment: Well the dropdown is not intended to be a child of tabs in bulma.   If you really need that structure, then you have to make some overrides/adjustments

Comment: @anderssonola yeah I suspect this, but I did hope in a more elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the `.tabs` statement.

```
.tabs.is-boxed a:not(.dropdown-item) {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

This way, it won't affect any dropdown anchor anymore.

---

**Edit, Another way:**

```
.tabs.is-boxed a.dropdown-item {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: True, but then if the Bulma framework is updated I have to check manually (everytime) that the definition is not changed. Don't I?

Comment: Well, just do not update Bulma. Btw, you should not update your external resources at all while working on a project. It could cause many issues.

Comment: Sure it could, but they may have spot issues that get fixed. If one follows this reasoning then no upgrade at all should be made to software, that has no sense. Instead I expect tests blinding everything. But still, one should remember that the original style has been lost

Comment: Anyway, for now is a +1, if no better answer will come I will accept the solution

Comment: So, I tried the solution, but doesn't work. I think that the imported CSS is not overridden. So it looks like the `:not` part is being ignored.

Comment: Are you using a CDN or a local file? Did you edit the statement as follow directly in the Bulma file?

Comment: I'm importing Bulma using the depency specified in the `dependency.json`

Comment: So your only way is to reset the styles applied to the anchors. I edit my answer.